# php session data sometimes getting lost

Tags: php, session

we have a PHP session problem.

Sometimes our application lost sessions. A schema can not be determined. Most times (99,9%) no error occurs.

It is a very large application (over 7,000 PHP pages). The source code has not been changed since the problem occurs. PHP runs on IIS 7.5 and Windows Server 2008.

The session ID is properly transferred from the cookie. The session files that are affected are either no longer available or empty or missing data. It looks as if the data were deleted because the file structure looks correct.

The session locking works.

The sessions are stored on a SAN. We have already saved the session temporarily on an internal hard drive. Same result.

Does anyone have an idea solving the problem?

kind regards

Paul

PS. Sorry about my english!

Comment: Is all of the session data for that user lost or only part of the session data?

Comment: did you check what your session timeout period is? Sessions aren't normally permanently persisted, and get cleaned up after a certain period.

Comment: Yes, I checked the session timeouts.

Comment: Some sessions are complete lost, some empty and some only a part of the session data.

Comment: Maybe you are running out of space where you are saving your sessions? It's just shooting in the dark

Answer (score -1):

If you have session try session handler. You probably don't want to hard code all those pages but surely there is one or more losing it. Also, this is attributed to browser limitations. If I start up a session on IE and then admin login in Chrome will kill the first session inherently as other session is no longer recognized when reverted SAN. BTW your session timeout period is not mentioned but your talking about (over 7,000 PHP pages). I would advise you create a session variable and pass it around instead of relying on cookie unless your pages orchestrate release or renew a lot hence why your using cookies. Your going to have to make sure all variable sets are unique first though.

Answer (score -1):

You should check on your every page if a particular session is set or not. This is a good programming technique. Have you used it in your php code? 
You can search for the page where your data is getting lost and then apply the php code in that page.

```
    if(isset($_POST['your_session'])){
//body;
}
else{
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">'.
        'alert("Session not set !");'.
        '</script>';
}
```

By this code, you will get the error on behalf of your sessions.